# exercise about $\frak p|\mu$ in an extension

Tags: number-theory

It's exercice 17-10 in H. Cohn " A classical invitation to ..."
Let $\mu\in\cal O_k$ and $\sqrt\mu\notin\cal O_k$. $\frak p$ a prime ideal, $v_{\frak p}(\mu)=2p$ then, it existe $\mu^*\in\cal O_k$, $\sqrt{\mu/\mu^*}\in k$ such that $(\frak p,\mu^*)=1$

I just had the idea to take an uniformizing $\pi\in\frak p\backslash\frak p^2$ and so what ?
What about $\mu/\pi^{2p}$ ?
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

In the localization $(O_k)_{\mathfrak{p}}$ you have $\mu = \pi^{2p} u$ where $u$ is a unit, so $u=a/b$ with $a,b\in O_k-\mathfrak{p}$,

then let $\mu^* = ab$.